# When verbs have 2 objects

Tags: sentence-construction, passive-voice

If someone is giving a cup of tea to me, can I rephrase it these ways:

1. I am being given a cup of tea by someone.
2. A cup of tea is being given to me by someone.

And if I owe someone some money, can I rephrase these ways:

1. Some money is owed to someone by me.
2. Someone is owed some money by me.

Thank you!

Comment: Yes, but there are not two objects. They are both passives and different sentences. So, what's your question actually?

Comment: There are certainly two objects in each of the examples above.   And the question is also clear; @Vova is asking if the rephrasings given preserve meaning.

Answer (score 2):

There are certainly some sentences with two objects in English.

> He gave me a cup of tea.

> I owe Chris some money.

In both of these sentences, there is an indirect object ("me", "Chris"), and a direct object ("a cup of tea", "some money").

The direct object is the one the verb directly "acts on", and the indirect object has a similar function to a preposition - it can tell us what or whom the verb acts for, by, on, and so forth.

There is an actual prepositional phrase in the sentence that does this in your examples:

> I am being given a cup of tea **by someone**.

> Some money is owed to someone **by me**.

When this happens, the secondary objects there ("someone", "me") would generally be called the "object of the preposition".  Although it's not entirely wrong to think of these like indirect objects, we would not call these "objects of the verb", and true indirect objects always come before the direct objects in the sentence.

It is OK to rephrase the sentences marked "1" above with those marked "2" - their meaning is very close.  In the second example, there is a switch to the passive voice between "1" and "2".  The first two are closer to each other because they are both passive.  "2" is more natural in each example.  English listeners would understand exactly the same meaning in both cases, however.

Comment: "Someone is owed some money by me" means I owe someone some money, right? I don't see the switch. The "I" is the subject, the "someone" and the "some money" are both the objects.